# A tight bound for the function

Tags: self-study

I am thinking about a tight bound in the form of two functions that sandwich the following function,
$$
f(x)=\bigg(\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}\bigg)^y 
$$
where $y$ is a non-negative constant and $x\in \mathbb{R}$. I am not sure if it is possible to have the bound with respect to both $x$ and $y$? I know the upper bound is one and the lower bound is zero. so, any suggestion about a tight bound?

Comment: $f(x)$ is simultaneously the tightest possible upper and lower bound for $f(x)$.  This shows that you need to provide more information in the form of constraints: what kind of formula would constitute a "bound"? What would be the purpose of this bound? What values of $x$ are possible? How is this question related to statistics and machine learning?

Comment: It will depend on the possible values for $x$. If $x$ is restricted to some  closed set $x\in [x_{min}, x_{max}]$ then: (1) argue that $f$ is monotonically increasing, either using derivative or composition rules and then (2) it should be fairly clear the values of $x$ for which $f$ achieves its minimum or maximum value. On the other hand, if $x$ belongs to some open set, $f$ will never achieve its infimum or supremum, but they are still (basically by definition) tight bounds.

Comment: @Matthew There is a more fundamental issue to address before this question can be answered: what is a "bound"? Your interpretation (the sup and inf as $x$ ranges over a domain) is reasonable but there are others. For instance, the OP might be seeking "simpler" functions $U$ and $L$ for which $L(x,y) \le f(x) \le U(x,y)$ for all $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @whuber wouldn't the tightest bounds still be the infimum and supremum over some space of functions rather some set of scalars? But yeah, who knows in what space they want the tightest bound...

Answer (score 1):

- $ h(x) = \frac{e^x}{1 + e^x} $ is a monotonically increasing function with range $(0, 1)$.
- $ g(x) = x^c $ is a monotonically increasing function for $x \geq 0$, $c > 0$.
- The composite of two monotone functions is also monotone hence $f(x) = g(h(x))$ is monotonically increasing as well for $c>0$.

Let $x_{min}$ be the smallest value of $x$ and $x_{max}$ be the largest value. Then for any $x$ we have:

$$ f(x_{min}) \leq f(x) \leq f(x_{max}) $$

You might also be confused about open vs. closed sets and a minimum vs. an infimum. If $x$ belongs to the open set $(-\infty, \infty)$ and $c > 0$, then a minimum and maximum value of $f$ do not exist. Instead, $0$ and $1$ are the [infimum and supremum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum) respectively of $f$. The infimum is the greatest lower bound and the supremum is the least upper bound (basically generalizes the notion of min and max).

The infimum and supremum are by definition the tightest bounds that exist!

Comment: The second point is not true, just take the example of x=0.5 and the function is decreasing.

Comment: That's incorrect, Rose.  Also, your attempted counterexample makes no sense because it says nothing about whether $h$ or $g$ or their composition is increasing.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot understand why $.5^2=.25$ is less than $.5^3=.125$

Comment: @whuber further, what do you mean by $max(x)$. I guess you think this is a random variable. It is a function not a RV. As I mentioned the maximum value of the function is 1 where happens in $x=\infty$ and the minimum is 0 where happens in $-infty$. I appreciate your answer but it has two issues, first it is more statistical than mathematical, second, it provides nothing more than what we already know.

Comment: @Rose You specifically said, "where $y$ is a non-negative constant and $x \in \mathcal{R}.$" Your example with $.5^2 = .25 $ and $.5^3 = .125$ involves **different values of** $y$! Specifically, it involves $y=2$ and $y=3$. That contradicts your statement that $y$ is a constant.

Comment: @MatthewGunn yes you right,thanks. What about other points?

Comment: Rose, this is a *statistics* site, so of course we will give statistical answers!  However, I do not conceive of $x$ as a random variable.  I take you at your word and suppose it is any real number.  A statement about the value of $f$ for one particular $x$ says nothing at all about whether $f$ is increasing. Note that if you are asking for $\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}}(f(x))$, *it does not exist.*  However, the *supremum* exists and equals $1$ for any $y\ge 0$. But that's such a trivial (purely mathematical) observation that I doubt it's what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @whuber I see but I am looking for two functions that sandwiches f(x). for example $x-1/n\leq x\leq x+1/n, n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: That's precisely why we cannot tell what you're asking, Rose.  Take *any* non-negative function $g$.  Then $f+g$ and $f-g$ sandwich $f$. You need to supply additional constraints on $f\pm g$ if this is to have any useful answer.